Система репорт для VK бота
Суть в том что бот сам по себе реогирует на команду /report но проблема что у меня не получается сделать лог чата, то есть куда будет уходить информация и репорте сама по себе
if command in ['report', 'репорт', 'rep', 'реп']:
            if not message.reply_message and len(arguments) < 2:
                await message.reply("Пожалуйста, укажите причину репорта или ответьте на сообщение, чтобы отправить репорт.", disable_mentions=1)
                return True

            target_user = None
            if message.reply_message:
                target_user = message.reply_message.from_id 
            elif len(arguments) >= 2 and await getID(arguments[1]):
                target_user = await getID(arguments[1]) 
        
            if not target_user:
                await message.reply("Не удалось определить пользователя для репорта.", disable_mentions=1)
                return True
                       
            reason = await get_string(arguments, 2) if len(arguments) > 2 else "Без причины"

            reporter_name = await get_user_name(user_id, chat_id)
            target_name = await get_user_name(target_user, chat_id)
            report_message = {
                "reporter_id": user_id,
                "reporter_name": reporter_name,
                "target_id": target_user,
                "target_name": target_name,
                "reason": reason
            }

            if message.reply_message:
                report_message["message_link"] = f"https://vk.com/your_chat_link?w=wall{chat_id}_{message.reply_message.id}"

            print(f"Отправляем репорт на сервер: {report_message}")  

            try:
                url = "https://vk.com/im/convo/2000000371?entrypoint=list_all&tab=all"  
                async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
                    async with session.post(url, json=report_message) as response:
                        if response.status == 200:
                            await message.reply("✅ Ваш вопрос был успешно отправлен! Ожидайте, в ближайшее время Агент поддержки @rose_manager обработает обращение!", disable_mentions=1)
                        else:
                            await message.reply("Ошибка при отправке репорта на сервер.", disable_mentions=1)
            except Exception as e:
                print(f"Ошибка при отправке репорта на сервер: {e}")
                await message.reply(f"Не удалось отправить репорт. Ошибка: {e}", disable_mentions=1)


Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Я имею ввиду что мне нужно понять как сделать лог чатов для репортов ведь у меня не получается, помогите дописать код
